# Memory error while accessing ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I'm getting a memory error. I'm getting a memory error because the memory usage increases exponentially. Clearly I am not releasing something, any ideas what that may be?

Here is my method to determine red pixels present in a UI image. It returns the count.

```
- (NSUInteger)getRedPixelCount:(UIImage*)image
{
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels = 0;

struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*) calloc(1, image.size.width * image.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
if (pixels != nil)
{
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate((void *) pixels,
                                                 image.size.width,
                                                 image.size.height,
                                                 8,
                                                 image.size.width * 4,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                 (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    if (context != NULL)
    {
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
        NSUInteger numberOfPixels = image.size.width * image.size.height;

        while (numberOfPixels > 0) {
            if (pixels->r == 255) {
                numberOfRedPixels++;

            } 
            pixels++;
            numberOfPixels--;
        }
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }
}
return numberOfRedPixels;
```

}

This is the code to iterate through the photo library images and determine each of their red pixels.

```
[self.library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

            if (asset) {
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];

                if (iref){

                        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];

                        NSLog(@"%i", [self getRedPixelCount:myImage]);
                }
            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
```

Regards,
C.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to call 'fullResolutionImage' in a cycle. This is very nice candidate for creating memory problems in your code. Anyway you can profile your code in the Instruments and see exactly what is going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not releasing the memory allocated by

```
struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*) calloc(1, image.size.width * image.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
```

You need to add:

```
free(pixels);
```

at the bottom of the if(pixels != nil) block.

Make the first block look like:

```
- (NSUInteger)getRedPixelCount:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels = 0;

    struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*) calloc(1, image.size.width * image.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
    if (pixels != nil)
    {
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate((void *) pixels,
                                                     image.size.width,
                                                     image.size.height,
                                                     8,
                                                     image.size.width * 4,
                                                     CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                     (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

        if (context != NULL)
        {
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
            NSUInteger numberOfPixels = image.size.width * image.size.height;
            struct pixels* ptr = pixels;

            while (numberOfPixels > 0) {
                if (ptr->r == 255) {
                    numberOfRedPixels++;

                } 
                ptr++;
                numberOfPixels--;
            }
            CGContextRelease(context);
        }
        free(pixels);
    }
    return numberOfRedPixels;
}
```

Also it will help if the second block changes to include:

```
        @autoreleasepool {
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];

            if (iref){

                UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];

                NSLog(@"%i", [self getRedPixelCount:myImage]);
                <#statements#>
            }
        }
```

although the major leak is not freeing the pixel buffer.

Comment: Yes, obviously this is the main problem here =)

Comment: When I add free(pixels) at the end of the if(pixels != nil) block (basically before the return statement). I get this error.

malloc: *** error for object 0x108f43000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: You're getting the error on free because of "pixels++" use "pixels[--numberOfPixels].r" and don't adjust them later or store a copy of the original pixels value away and free that.

Answer (score 0):

You can embrace 'enumerateAssetsUsingBlock' block with @autorelease:

```
@autorelease {

   if (asset) {

      ...
   }
}
```

This force all autoreleasing objects to release immediately.

UPD:
Use [asset thumbnail] instead of fullScreenImage or fullResolutionImage. These methods generate huge amount of pixel data.

UPD2:
if even [asset thumbnail] did not help, than you must find a way to release this image data, it could be little bit tricky as long as you can't to release it directly calling CGImageRelease. Try something like this:

```
NSMutabelArray* arr = [NSMutabelArray new];
```

In your enumerateAssetsUsingBlock just put asset object in this array:

```
[arr addObject:asset];
```

And do nothing else in this block.

Then iterate through this array in a way:

```
while (arr.count > 0)
{
   ALAsset* asset = [arr lastObject];
   // do smth with asset
   [arr removeLastObject]; // this will remove object from memory immediatelly
}
```

Comment: still not working, memory usage continues to increase.

Comment: I assume that fullResolutionImage generates image data and store it until ALAsset object alive. And this data could be very big (f.e. 10mb) even for one image. So, the solution depends on what you are trying to solve. If just find all red pictures in your library, then using [asset thumbnailImage] will be pretty enough for this per-pixel analysing.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried that but it does take thumbnailImage,
No visible @interface for 'ALAssetRepresentation' declares the selector 'thumbnailImage'

Comment: Sorry, its name is [asset thumbnail].

Comment: That just slows the growth of the memory usage down. It does not release what is on it. nor does using autoreleasepool(arc).

Comment: Tried UPD2, still not working. I think I need to release the ALAssetRepresentation or CGImageRef

Comment: Just try @David's answer.